# How can I create non-repeating palindromic numbers?

Tags: haskell, numbers

So I'm trying to do something and it's almost there I think but I can't solve the last part of it. I have to make a code where someone gives a number (let's make it 22) an I need to find all the palindromic numbers there is when I multiply two numbers smaller than 22:

> Find all the palindromic numbers of `a*b` but `a < n && b < n`. but they can't repeat themselves.

I got this

```
calc :: Int -> [Int]
calc n = [a*b|a<-[1..n-1], b<-[a..n-1], a*b>10, reverse(show(a*b))==show(a*b)]
```

If we do `calc 22` the result should be

```
[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,171,121,252,272,323]
```

but I'm getting

```
[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,171,121,252,252,272,323]
```

because 14x18 = 12x21 = 252.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please check that my edit actually fulfills your needs. Otherwise [edit] the post yourself.

Comment: IT's amazing! Thank you!!

Comment: This isn't solving the problem with your algorithm, but I would probably just pipe it through `Data.Set.toList . Data.Set.fromList` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to make sure that every number is unique. There exist multiple representations for all numbers with at least three prime factors (`x * y * z = (x * y) * z = x * (y * z)`). So one way we could tacke this would be prime factor analysis and reasoning about them. But that's probably an overkill.

Instead, we can use a function that makes sure that every number in our sorted list is unique:

```
unique :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
unique (x:y:xs) = if x == y then unique (y:xs) else x : unique (y:xs)
unique xs       = xs
```

(Alternatively, use `unique = map head . group`)

Now you can use `sort` from `Data.List` and you end up with your actual `calUniuqe`:

```
calcUnique :: Int -> [Int]
calcUnique = unique . sort . calc
```

However, we can make `calc` a lot easier to read if we move the palindrome check into its own function:

```
isPalindrome :: Int -> Bool
isPalindrome n = n > 10 && reverse n' == n'
  where n' = show n

calc :: Int -> [Int]
calc n = [a * b | a <- [1..n-1], b <- [a..n-1], isPalindrome (a * b)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very helpfull!